# In elasticsearc How can I Tokenize words separeted by space and be able to match by typing without space

Tags: elasticsearch, matching, analyzer

Here is what I want to achieve :

My field value : "one two three"
I want to be able to match this field by typing: one or onetwo or onetwothree or onethree or twothree or two or three

For that, the tokenizer need to produce those tokens:
one
onetwo
onetwothree
onethree
two
twothree
three

Do you know how can I implement this analyzer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is the same problem in German language when we connect different words into one. For this purpose Elasticsearch uses technique called "coumpound words". There is also a specific token filter called "compound word token filter". It is trying to find sub-words from given dictionary in string. You only have to define dictionary for your language. There is whole specification at link bellow.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/analysis-compound-word-tokenfilter.html